# Mysql UPDATE first column in a row that doesn't equal ''

Tags: mysql

I have a db that has multiple columns with follow the "**name_***" syntax. Basically I wanna use UPDATE in a query so that it updates the first column where the value of it is equal to ''.

I found this so far:

```
UPDATE table SET
`name_1` = CASE WHEN `name_1` = '' then 'something' else name_1 end,
`name_2` = CASE WHEN `name_2` = '' then 'something' else name_2 end,
`name_3` = CASE WHEN `name_3` = '' then 'something' else name_3 end
WHERE ID = '$id_example'
```

Now that would be perfect, except it does all of them. I want to select only the first one, where it equals '' and then set the rest to what they were before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting first your desired column, that would be a good practice.

"SELECT * FROM table WHERE value= first"

Then

YOUR UPDATE QUERY

Comment: That was my first idea, but what if 2 users login in at the same time and both have there SELECT's return that it's empty and it executes a UPDATES. One user will overwrite the other.

Comment: I see, are you trying to say if 2 users will logged in every update should be like first come first update or something like user1 updates the first record then user2 would update the second record?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Then when the entire row is full it will just insert a new row and have all the other columns blank waiting for people to fill it.

Comment: adding a column for status at the end of your table would help like "STATUS = TRUE/FALSE" ex: if users login "SELECT MIN(id) FROM tble WHERE status = false"... hope it would help

Comment: That would work just as well too, but I could also do it like 
`UPDATE table SET
'name_1' = CASE WHEN 'name_1' = '' then 'something' else name_1 end,
'name_2' = CASE WHEN 'name_1' != '' and 'name_2' = '' then 'something' else name_2 end,
'name_3' = CASE WHEN 'name_1' != '' and 'name_2' != '' and 'name_3' = '' then 'something' else name_3 end
WHERE ID = '$id_example'` Not sure which way would most reliable..?

Comment: Using CASE would be not reliable, example when records or values change you cannot go again to your code and add your CASE Operator again?!?!?

Comment: true, but the time between SELECT and UPDATE on the server could have someone overwrite your data if enough people are accessing the page. It's kind of hard to say, because if I use the UPDATE method I can check and update in one query with no worrys of overwrites but SELECT can change to wrap around my DB structure and will allow for more options after the select...

Comment: I think I might just go with the INSERT method so I can reduce my code a bit but if you want to edit your answer with your method in the comments I can give you a upvote and checkmark cause your way work perfectly fine too.

Comment: its not bad to add more queries and conditions in your program so why not try nested if unless you have problems in the structure of your database that would be hard to explain the solution here...

Comment: It's mostly cause if it lags out the data could be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET
`name_1` = CASE WHEN `name_1` = '' then 'something' else name_1 end,
`name_2` = CASE WHEN `name_1` != '' and `name_2` = '' then 'something' else name_2 end,
`name_3` = CASE WHEN `name_1` != '' and `name_2` != '' and `name_3` = '' then 'something' else name_3 end
WHERE ID = '$id_example'
```

Comment: That will work perfect except I got 18+ columns to check so if there isn't anything better this should work.